# how to send this txtPath to encrpt.addActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

I am trying to select a .txt file using `JFileChooser` and store it in a `JTextField`.  I named the field `txtPath`  The problem is that it is not reading the `txtPath`.

```
txtPath.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());

---

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
  File f = new File(txtPath);
  int ch;

  StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
  FileInputStream fin = null;
  try
  {
    fin = new FileInputStream(f);
    while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
      strContent.append((char) ch);
    fin.close();
  } 
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
  System.out.println("Original string: " +strContent.toString()+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
File f = new File(txtPath.getText());
```

instead of:

```
File f = new File(txtPath);
```

Otherwise you are feeding the File constructor an object reference, not the text contained in the JTextField object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use method getText() to first extract string from text field